# DotNetNuke Partial Class Control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, parameters, dotnetnuke

I am using DotNetNuke and creating an ASCX call TutorialsAll.ascx and a second one called TutorialsByLevel.ascx. TutorialsByLevel.ascx is used 4 time currently in TutorialsAll.ascx.

In TutorialsByLevels.ascx I have a Public Property `TutorialTypeID` which is begin fired from TutorialsAll.ascx.

I have added the code below is anyone has any ideas why not and how I can make it work, much appriciated.

**TutorialsAll.ascx:**

```xml
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TutorialsAll.ascx.vb" Inherits="Portals_0_open_TutorialsAll" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mark" TagName="tutorial" Src="TutorialsByLevel.ascx" %>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic1" TutorialType=1 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic2" TutorialType=2 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic3" TutorialType=3 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic4" TutorialType=4 runat="server" /></div>
```

**TutorialsByLevel.ascx:**

```
Partial Class Portals_0_open_TutorialsByLevel
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Dim _Type As Integer

Public Property TutorialType(ByVal TypeID As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        Return _Type
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Type = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteSqlServer").ToString)
    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Prez_Stories WHERE Tut_Show = 1 AND Tut_Level = " & _Type & "ORDER BY Tut_Order"
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    myReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("")

    s.Append("<div=""tutorialBlock"">TutorialType = " & _Type)
    Do While myReader.Read
        s.Append("<div id=""newTutorial"">" & myReader("Title"), "<br/>" & myReader("Summary") & "<div>")
    Loop
    s.Append("</div>")

    Literal1.Text = s.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry missed out TutorialsAll.ascx page.

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="mark" TagName="tutorial" Src="TutorialsByLevel.ascx" %>


<div class="Tut_Column">
    <mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic1" TutorialType=1 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic2" TutorialType=2 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic3" TutorialType=3 runat="server" /></div>
<div class="Tut_Column"><mark:tutorial ID="TutorialBasic4" TutorialType=4 runat="server" /></div>

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. Note that you can edit your own question at any time to improve it (which may also bump your question). It's not clear though from the text: what is your exact question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark,

Trying to remember but I think you might have to move your Page_Load code to prerender event. If I remember correctly (and its been some time since I have worked on a project that I did this with) the property is populated too late in the page cycle to work in the pageload you have to process in the prerender.

I could be wrong -----:)

Comment: At the time I wanted to try something new but it got too frustrating to sort out and went back to a traditional method